# How to create a multi-layer perceptron in Matlab for a multi-class dataset

Tags: matlab, perceptron

I want to create a double layered perceptron for an assignment.
It will act as a classifier for the Fisher iris data set.

I've come across the following problems while creating the network:

- For a dataset like the above, can i setup the network with a single
  input and pass the whole training matrix of n rows and 4 features as
  an input value? Or, do i need to adjust the network to use 4 input
  node, 1 for each feature, and pass the training matrix as an input
  value?
- Furthermore, how do I properly connect the layers with each other?
  For instance, when i create a perceptron with 4 inputs using the
  network command, I don't really understand what do the biasConnect, inputConnect and layerConnect actually do.
- Lastly, how many outputs do i need to correctly classify one element?
  Every example I've come across uses one output, but, will just one
  suffice? Or, do I need one for each class?

Command used for creating the network mentioned at the second point:

```
net = network(4, 2, [1; 0], [1 1 1 1;0 0 0 0], [0 0; 1 0], [0 1]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with network connections. The way the `network` function works is not intuitevely clear. In order to control if your input vectors describe the structure correctly, you can use `view(net)` :

[image]

Now let's discuss each parameter shortly:

`numInputs` - if your network will get only one input data set, you need to put `1` here.

`numLayers` - for the iris data set it's ok to use `2` here.

`biasConnect` - bias units are used to "increase" non-linearity between inputs and outputs. We want the network to be able to approximate complex non-linear functions, that is why it's a good idea to add bias units to both layers. So put here `[1, 1]`.

`inputConnect` - the vector has dimensions `numLayers-by-numInputs`. It shows which inputs are connected to which layers. You have only one input connected to the first layer, so put `[1;0]` here.

`layerConnect` - the vector has dimensions `numLayers-by-numLayers`. You have two layers. The first layer is connected to the second one, but not to itself. There is no connection going from the second layer to the first one, and the second layer does not feed itself. Put `[0 0; 1 0]` here.

`outputConnect` - the vector has dimensions `1-by-numLayers` and shows which layer is connected to the output. Put `[0 1]` here.

Here is our command and the corresponding graph:

```
net = network(1, 2, [1; 1], [1;0], [0 0; 1 0], [0 1]);
```

[image]

You can experiment with the parameters and the resulting structures can be very complex.

**Network configuration**

Now you need to configure the network. You can find all the parameters in the documentation, I will discribe here the most important:

1. It's important to set correct activation functions for the layers. By default the function is set to `purelin`. You may want to use here something like `tansig` or `logsig`.
2. You need to set the size of each layer. In your case I would use 5 or 7 units in the first layer. The size of the second layer should be equal to the number of output classes: `3` in your case.
3. The initialization functions for the weights and bias units should be set for each layer as well.

The resulting network looks like here:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
net = network(1, 2, [1; 1], [1;0], [0 0; 1 0], [0 1]);

net.adaptFcn = 'adaptwb';
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand'; %Set the divide function to dividerand (divide training data randomly).

net.performFcn = 'mse';
net.trainFcn = 'trainlm'; % set training function to trainlm (Levenberg-Marquardt backpropagation) 

net.plotFcns = {'plotperform', 'plottrainstate', 'ploterrhist', 'plotconfusion', 'plotroc'};

%set Layer1
net.layers{1}.name = 'Layer 1';
net.layers{1}.dimensions = 7;
net.layers{1}.initFcn = 'initnw';
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';

%set Layer2
net.layers{2}.name = 'Layer 2';
net.layers{2}.dimensions = 3;
net.layers{2}.initFcn = 'initnw';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'tansig';

[x,t] = iris_dataset; %load of the iris data set
net = train(net,x, t); %training

y = net(x); %prediction

view(net);
```

The confusion matrices look pretty good. So the network works well!

[image]

**A little bit shoter way**

If you want to use an already preinstalled network, you can use this code:

```
[x,t] = iris_dataset;
net = patternnet;
net = configure(net,x,t);

net = train(net,x,t); %training
view(net);

y = net(x); %predict
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you have spent making this I really appreciate it